# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on this face recognition system.I have a folder with subfolders that has face images inside it. I am trying to loop through all the subfolders that consists of images and use my 'align_face' function that detects the face and crops and aligns all the images in subfolders. It then has to save all the aligned and cropped in another folder

I have tried this:

```
def align_face(imagePath):
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(imagePath)
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
    face_landmarks = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
    if len(face_locations) == 0:
        print("Couldn't detect face for pid {} in path {}".format(Id,imagePath))
        return []
    if len(face_locations) > 1:
        return []
    else:
        (top, right, bottom, left) = face_locations[0]
        desiredWidth = (right - left)
        desiredHeight = (bottom - top)
        leftEyePts = face_landmarks[0]['left_eye']
        rightEyePts = face_landmarks[0]['right_eye']
        if len(leftEyePts) == 0 or len(rightEyePts) == 0:
            print("Couldn't detect both eyes for pid {} in path {}".format(Id,imagePath))
            return []
        else:
            leftEyeCenter = np.array(leftEyePts).mean(axis=0).astype("int")
            rightEyeCenter = np.array(rightEyePts).mean(axis=0).astype("int")
            leftEyeCenter = (leftEyeCenter[0],leftEyeCenter[1])
            rightEyeCenter = (rightEyeCenter[0],rightEyeCenter[1])
            dY = rightEyeCenter[1] - leftEyeCenter[1]
            dX = rightEyeCenter[0] - leftEyeCenter[0]
            
            angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(dY, dX))
            desiredLeftEye=(0.35, 0.35)
            desiredFaceWidth = desiredWidth
            desiredFaceHeight = desiredHeight
            desiredRightEyeX = 1.0 - desiredLeftEye[0]
            dist = np.sqrt((dX ** 2) + (dY ** 2))
            desiredDist = (desiredRightEyeX - desiredLeftEye[0])
            
            desiredDist *= desiredFaceWidth
            scale = desiredDist / dist
            
            eyesCenter = ((leftEyeCenter[0] + rightEyeCenter[0]) // 2,
                (leftEyeCenter[1] + rightEyeCenter[1]) // 2)
            M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(eyesCenter, angle, scale)
            
            tX = desiredFaceWidth * 0.5
            tY = desiredFaceHeight * desiredLeftEye[1]
            M[0, 2] += (tX - eyesCenter[0])
            M[1, 2] += (tY - eyesCenter[1])
            
            (w, h) = (desiredFaceWidth, desiredFaceHeight)
            output = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            output = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            print("images aligned")
            
            return output
```

```
#Now that we have defined the face alignmet and cropping, we walk through each subfolder and use the align function
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('<path to subdirectories that has face pictures>'):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
        with open(fpath, 'rb') as f, open('<path to new folder to store cropped and aligned picture>', 'w') as newfile:
            data = f.read()
            new_data = align_face(data) #Implementing align_face function 
            newfile.write(new_data)
```

However, I keep getting an error.

**AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'**

Does anyone know why?Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Full error is this:
[image]

Comment: So it should be `align_face(fpath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `align_face` is the name of the file containing the image data, not the image data. So you don't need to open and read the data in your loop.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('<path to subdirectories that has face pictures>'):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
        with open('<path to new folder to store cropped and aligned picture>', 'w') as newfile:
            new_data = align_face(fpath) #Implementing align_face function 
            newfile.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. However for some reason, new folder isn't created and a text file called 'face_recog' is created on the same folder with all the images subfolders.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with how you set `<path to new folder to store cropped and aligned picture>`.